# Multithreading for perl code

Tags: multithreading, perl

I need to know how to implement multi threading for the following code . I need to call this script every second but the sleep timer processes it after 2 seconds . In total script call itself after every 3 seconds. But i need to call it every second , can anybody provide me a solution to it or point me to right direction.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

sub print
{
local $gg = time;
print "$gg\n";
}

$oldtime = (time + 1);
while(1)
{
if(time > $oldtime)
{
    &print();
    sleep 2;
    $oldtime = (time + 1);
            }
        }
```

Its just an example.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Here is a simple example of using threads:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub threaded_task {
    threads->create(sub { 
        my $thr_id = threads->self->tid;
        print "Starting thread $thr_id\n";
        sleep 2; 
        print "Ending thread $thr_id\n";
        threads->detach(); #End thread.
    });
}

while (1)
{
    threaded_task();
    sleep 1;
}
```

This will create a thread every second.  The thread itself lasts two seconds.

To learn more about threads, please see [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads.html).  An important consideration is that variables are not shared between threads.  Duplicate copies of all your variables are made when you start a new thread.

If you need shared variables, [look into `threads::shared`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html).

*However, please note that the correct design depends on what you are actually trying to do. Which isn't clear from your question.*

Some other comments on your code:

- Always `use strict;` to help you use best practices in your code.
- The correct way to declare a lexical variable is `my $gg;` rather than `local $gg;`. `local` doesn't actually create a lexical variable; it gives a localized value to a global variable. It is not something you will need to use very often.
- Avoid giving subroutines the same name as system functions (e.g. `print`).  This is confusing.
- It is not recommended to use `&` before calling subroutines (in your case it was necessary because of conflict with a system function name, but as I said, that should be avoided).

Comment: Good answer. To you know what is a good source for understanding threads in terms of multiple threads reading and writing the same global variables at the same time?

Comment: @Myforwik, please see the update to the answer.  Variables are not shared between threads.  You need to use `threads::shared` for that.  The two documentation links I added to the answer should help with understanding that.