# Can multithreading be used to run 100 perl scripts in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, performance, perl, fork, command-line-interface

Here is my problem:

I have 100 perl scripts which were created over time; each script takes its own time--from 5 minutes to 5 hours.

Today I am running all these scripts from command prompt in a sequential manner as a suite, and it takes close to 1.5 days to run all of them.

I am wondering if 100 command prompts can be opened simultaneously, and if I can run one perl script on each command prompt in parallel...so all my scripts can complete in 5 hours (the maximum time a single script takes).

Is this possible by any tool?

Can we use multithreading to achieve the above?

Please suggest what is the better way to appraoch?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
perl script1
perl script2
...
perl script100
```

you can do

```
perl script1 &
perl scipt2 &
 ...
perl script100       # no & here!
```

This is not exactly multithreading, though.

If you have all scripts, and only those scripts in a dedicated directory (say `parscripts`), you can do the following:

```
for s in parscripts/*.pl;do perl $s & ;done
wait
echo "All scripts completed."
```

But this, of course presupposes that the scripts are independent! See also @KlasLindbäcks answer.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck In fact, single line `dothis & dothat` is quite common. But you're right, in a script one would write it without the backslashes.

Comment: Even better would be looping

Comment: @m0skit0 Probably not in this case. The actual scripts can have any name, the names `script1...n` are just placeholders in the answer.

Comment: If scripts are on the same directory, you can actually just read their names from there.

Answer (score 2):

Starting scripts in parallel is easy.

In Linux/Unix just add an ampersand at the end of each command to start it in the background.

Example:

```
myscript &
```

You need to be aware of 2 things:

Some scripts may have dependencies to each other, so that they should not be started until some other script has completed.

The total time may be longer than 5 hours because of bottlenecks when several scripts run in parallel.

The first problem is solved by group dependent scripts into script files, så your start script may look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
perl script1 &
perl script2 &
script_group1 &
script_group2 &
...
```

Where a script group would look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Note that there is no '&' at the end of these lines,
# because they need to run consecutively:
perl dependentscript1 
perl dependentscript2
perl dependentscript3
```

Comment: That's not multithreading, it's multiprocessing. Multithreading is explained here for e.g. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429183/multithreading-for-perl-code . But you're absolutely right, that's what the OP actually needs, it's just worth mentioning

Answer (score 2):

If these multiple scripts are needed to be run regularly, you should consider writing a shell script that calls them. Or, we could write a makefile.

A makefile should be used then when there are dependencies between various scripts, and you need to express “*`foo` needs to be run before `bar`*”. The `make` program will then automatically find a correct order that satisfies these dependencies. You can also specify how many parallel jobs `make` will start: `make -j 4` for four parallel jobs.

A makefile consists of recipies, which have dependencies and a body. In the body, each line is taken to be a shell command. The command will be printed to the terminal, and then executed. To suppress the printing, prefix the command with `@`. Example:

```
foo: bar something_else
<tab    >@ echo "I am about to execute the foo command:"
<tab    >perl /some/path/foo.pl

bar:
<tab    >@ echo "I am about to execute the bar:"
<tab    >perl /some/path/bar.pl

something_else
<tab    >perl /some/path/something.pl | perl /some/path/else.pl >/some/path/output.txt
```

The `<tab >` must be changed to a literal tab character. Intendation by whitespace doesn't work.

The disadvantage of this solution is that the makefile is three times as long as a simple shell script. The advantage is that you can directly specify how many parallel jobs you want (this gives even load without too much idling), and you don't have to manually order the scripts like *Klas Lindbäck* proposed in his answer. With `make` you'd just have to specify the actual dependencies.